# usage of apostrofe in grep rexExp

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I have recently started learning regExp and found nice example of it in shell using grep to extract only anchor tags url e.g `<a href="unix.stackexchange.com"></a>`

```
grep - 'href="[^"]*"' *.html
```

if i got it correct `'href="[^"]*"'` means to find `href="0-infinity character that does not have " in it "` but doesnt `*` have to be outside of the quotes?

and i am quite confused. the `' '` are used to escape special meaning of characters. SO `*` shouldnt work at all + `*.html` should mean = `0-infinte characters` that ends with .html = so is it possible to have two ragExp in one grep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the output is:

```
% grep -o 'href="[^"]*"' <<<'<a href="unix.stackexchange.com"></a>'
href="unix.stackexchange.com"
```

- The Regex pattern is `href="[^"]*"`, it is put inside single quotes to prevent it from shell interpretation
- `*.html` is the file(s) you are taking the Regex/`grep` action upon, here `*` is a shell filename generation pattern (matches any number of characters) that will result in all files in the current directory ending in `.html`
- `href="` will be matched literally
- `[^"]*` will match the substring till next `"`, `*` matches zero or more occurrences of the preceding token `[^"]` so if there is no characters between two `"`s then it will result in an empty string
- `"` matches a literal `"`

Comment: Thanks for answer  my fault i should have metioned that the full command is cat * | grep - 'href="[^"]*"' *.html  does *.html has the same meaning in even with cat command bein there?

Comment: @trolkura `cat` is totally unnecessary here..use do `grep href="[^"]*"' *.html does *.html` ..here `cat *` will concatenate all files in the current directory and then yo can run `grep 'href="[^"]*"' ` over that, in that case `*.html` after `grep` is redundant..anyway, avoid `cat` and just do `grep 'href="[^"]*"' *.html`